# how to obtain all permutation combination of two string?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

I have two words, and I want obtain all permutation of the combination of these words. The relative order of character from each string has to be preserved

look at this exapmle:

```
Input= "abc", "mn"

Output= "abcmn", "abmnc", "amnbc", "mnabc", "mabcn", "manbc", "mabnc", "ambnc", "ambcn", "abmcn"
```

I search stackoverflow.com, and achieve the following code, but it doesn't work!

```
void print_towstring(const std::vector<int>& v, const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
{
    std::size_t i1 = 0;
    std::size_t i2 = 0;

    for (int i : v) {
        std::cout << ((i == 0) ? s1[i1++] : s2[i2++]);
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void towstring(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2)
{
    std::vector<int> v(s1.size(), 0);

    v.insert(v.end(), s2.size(), 1);
    do
    {
        print_towstring(v, s1, s2);
    } while (std::next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    towstring("abc", "mn");
    return 0;
}
```

how can I write algorithm of permutation combination in c++ ?

Comment: I just noticed your question is similar [to this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21475239/permutations-of-array-in-char-typ). Are you guys in the same class?

Comment: yes, and I seen this question before asking. but that question doesn't help me at all!

Comment: The given code works : http://ideone.com/IYYVZY. I have tested it before answering to [show-all-state-of-tow-string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453875/show-all-state-of-tow-string)

Comment: it doesn't satisfied my need dear @Jarod42

Comment: @R.S: I posted an answer with a link to C++03 code (http://ideone.com/ZHXSkt). It outputs the same strings as required (but not in the same order).

Comment: this homework is definitely CS year 1 homework, either is C++ 2nd semester or introduction to algorithm. tutor will notice if you using algorithm library.

Comment: @R.S So when you wrote "... the following code, but it doesn't work", did you mean that it actually worked, but you needed a different version? Or did your code really fail to work? If so, you should clarify this with an example (input, output, expected output).

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it recursively. Basically at each step you create two branches: one where you add to your string a letter from the right hand side string, and another branch where you add the first letter from the left hand side string:

```
    void AddNext(
      std::string const& left,
      std::string const& right,
      std::string const& current,
      std::vector< std::string >& results)
    {
      if (left.empty())
      {
        current.append(right);
        results.push_back(current);
        return;
      }
      else if (right.empty())
      {
         current.append(left);
         results.push_back(current)
         return;
      }
      else
      {
        AddNext(left, right.substr(1, right.size() -1), current + std::string(1, right[0]), results);
        AddNext(left.substr(1, left.size() -1), right, current + std::string(1, left[0]), results);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you can represent a "permutation combination" by a sequence of 0's and 1's, where each number tells from which string to take next character, like this:

```
00101 - means abmcn
```

So, you now have to produce all such strings that have a given number of 0's and a given number of 1's (3 and 2 in your example). To do it, I guess, the easiest would be to iterate over all combinations of 0's and 1's, and throw away those that don't have the needed number of 1's.

I like to represent a string of bits by a number, starting from the least significant bit, e.g. 00101 corresponds to

```
0 * 2^0 +
0 * 2^1 +
1 * 2^2 +
0 * 2^3 +
1 * 2^4 = 20
```

(warning: this will only work for a limited string size - up to 32 - or whatever number of bits `int` has. For longer strings, the implementation could be adapted to 64 bits, but it's not worth it, because it would be too slow anyway)

To get a given bit from such a number:

```
int GetBit(int n, int b)
{
    return (n >> b) & 1;
}
```

To convert such a number to a vector:

```
void ConvertNumberToVector(int n, std::vector<int>& v)
{
    for (int b = 0; b < v.size(); ++b)
        v[b] = GetBit(n, b);
}
```

Then you can use this vector with your `print_towstring` function.

Comment: +1 for input mapping. Teachers will high five you if you come with such approach... It Can be scaled to arbitrary number of inputs. Can you just explain it a little bit better please ?

Comment: You can probably just write a std::vector<bool> with the value 00011 and then generate all the permutations of that. Then write something that will generate the string out of those permutations. That would solve the problem of having combinations that don't match with the size of the input string.

Comment: Better check for empty string input in that case.

Answer (score 2):

The(My) code works: http://ideone.com/IYYVZY

It just use C++11.
for C++03 see http://ideone.com/ZHXSkt

You have to change the for range loop

`for (int e : v)` -> `for (std::size_t i = 0, size = v.size(); i != size; ++i) { int e = v[i]; ..`

Answer (score 1):

I am going to build upon the approach from ***anatolyg*** to provide a solution for `n` input strings, lets say for the sake of simplicity `n <=10` (see where I am going?). Notice how the relative ordering for one string never change? This is the base of the algorithm

**step1 :** 
You take your string in a array or vector or whatever. for each string you assign a symbol of size one, like character `0` for the first one, `1` for the second, till `9`.

**steps2 :** you have a function which convert the inputs to a single string (or better a vector), where each character is from the original string. In your case, the function is :

```
 f("abc", "mn") => "00011"
```

**steps3 :** you enumerate the permutations over the resulting string, in this case "00011". You were already in the right track with `std::next_permutation()`

**steps4 :** you iterate on each of the resulting string and use its symbol as a mask. something like

```
void mergewithmask(std::string& target, std::string& input, char mask )
{
 int i = 0;//target index
 int j = 0;//input index
 for(i = 0; i < target.size(); i++)
 {
   if(target[i] == mask){
      target[i] = input[j];
      j++;
   }
 }
}
```

so

```
mergewithmask("01001","abc", `0`) => "a1bc1"
mergewithmask("a1bc1","mn", `1`) => "ambcn"
```

In order of this approach to work you need to use symbols which don't collide with your initial inputs. Using a vector of negative numbers for instance will guarantee not colliding with a char array and a unlimited amount of input strings...